# Prove that every real number $x \in [0,1]$ has a "certain" binary representation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers, binary, decimal-expansion

I want to prove that every real number $x \in [0,1]$ has binary representation in the following way:

Let $B$ denote the set of all sequences $b:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow\{0,1\}$. Consider then $f:B\rightarrow [0,1]$ defined by
$$
f(b)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k 2^{-k}.
$$
Then I want to prove that $f$ is surjective.

---

We can note that $f$ is indeed well-defined as by the comparison criterion then
$$
0\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k 2^{-k} \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k} = 1.
$$
and hence also convergent for all $b \in B$.

---

I have thought about three ideas for a proof:

(i) If we could show $f$ is continuous, then by the mean value property, this would hold. However this requires some thought into what are open sets in $B$ so I don't think this is the easiest route to take.

(ii) Using a similar idea as in (i), maybe we could somehow take a $b$ such that fraction of $b$'s elements that are 1 is exactly the number $r\in[0,1]$ we are trying to hit. However I can't quite construct this $b$.

(iii) The final and I think perhaps most promising idea is to use that we know every real number has decimal representation in the base-10 system. If we were somehow able to translate this representation into this one, then we would be done. Yet this has only just been trial and error so far for me.

Am I on the right track or is there something I am missing?

Comment: For any $x\in[0,1]$, solve the equation $f(b)=x$ using bisection. Let $I_0=[0,1]$. Divide $I_0$ at $m_1=1/2$. If $x\in[0,1/2)$ put $b_1=0$ and let $I_1=[0,1/2]$, otherwise put $b_1=1$ and $I_1=[1/2,1]$. Assume that you have defined $b_1,b_2,...,b_{n-1}$ and $I_{n-1}=[a,b]$. Let $m_n$ be the midpoint of $I_{n-1}$. If $x\in[a,m_{n})$ define $b_n=0$ and $I_n=[a,m_n]$, otherwise define $b_n=1$ and $I_n=[m_n,b]$.

Comment: For some numbers there isn't a unique solution. For example, $f(0.1000...)=f(0.0111...)=1/2$. The method above will obtain the first solution. To get the other solution close the first half and open the second half of the bisection above. Equivalently, replace a tail of $0s$ with $1$s and change the $1$ immediately before the tail of $0$s with a $0$. Except for $f(0.000...)=0$. This solution is unique.

Comment: Not related to your question directly, but I guess you mean the intermediate value property in your option i?

Answer (score 2):

[The same proof that shows each number has a decimal expansion also works for any other basis.](https://planetmath.org/existenceanduniquenessofdecimalexpansion)

---

However, if you don't want to just copy an existing proof, you can define $b_i$ exactly like so:

Let $n\in\mathbb N$ be arbitrary. Now, define $x_{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} b_k2^{-k}$.

Now, define

$$b_n = \begin{cases}0&\text{if}& x-x_{n-1} < 2^{-n}\\
1 &\text{if}&x-x_{n-1} \geq 2^{-n}\end{cases}$$

and you can then prove that, by construction, $x_n$ converges to $x$.

Comment: I have one question about the proof $x_n\to x$. I can prove that if $x-x_{n-1}<2^{-n}$, then $0\le x-x_n\le 2^{-n}$. Thus, $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k2^{-k}$. But it does not work for $x-x_{n-1}\ge 2^{-n}$? That means that $x-x_n\ge 0$...

Comment: @H.YDuan In either case, $b_n$ is selected such that $x-x_n < 2^{-n}$.

Comment: But for $x-x_{n-1}\ge 2^{-n}$, $x-x_n=x-x_{n-1}-2^{-n}\ge 2^{-n}-2^{-n}=0$? How about the another direction?

Comment: @H.YDuan A full proof would be inductive. In the inductive step, you already know that $x-x_{n-1} \leq 2\cdot 2^{-n}$, meaning you can only have two options, either $x-x_{n-1}$ is an element of $[0, 2^{-n}]$ or it is an element of $[2^{-n}, 2\cdot 2^{-n}]$.